# removing a class from an element inside a $watch with angular

Tags: css, angularjs

I want to remove a class on an element from within a $watch. The class would be removed after a $timeout of a 10 seconds.

Code looks something like this:

Controller:

```
$scope.$watch('lastPrice', function(newVal, oldVal){
    if ( newVal > oldVal ) {
        $scope.lastTick = 'up';
    } else if ( newVal < oldVal ) {
        $scope.lastTick = 'down';
    } else {
        $scope.lastTick = 'none';
    }

    $scope.last = newVal;

    $timeout(function(){
        //remove $scope.lastTick class name from element here
    }, 10000)
});
```

View:

```
<span class="last" ng-class="lastTick">{{lastPrice}}</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid using the `delete` operator here since it would mean that the `lastTick` could be accidentally inherited from the parent scope. Instead, I would recommend:

```js
$timeout(function () { $scope.lastTick = undefined; }, 10000);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9ebjt/1/

Comment: i just set `$scope.lastTick = 'none';` which works well with what I had intended anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try `delete` operator:

```
  $timeout(function(){
        delete $scope.lastTick;
    }, 10000);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/9ebjt/

Comment: This has the potential pitfall of accidentally inheriting the parent `$scope`'s `lastTick` value.